# Composition of functions where $f(g(x^2))$, how do you handle the $g(x^2)$ function?

Tags: functions

Plugging the question into symbolab, it only applies the square to the $x$ within the $g(x)$ function. Example: $f(x) = x^2 - 2$, $g(x) = x - 7$. Then $g(x^2) = x^2-7$. $f(g(x^2))$ becomes $x^4-14x^2+47$. The question is if this is correct, and if so, why?

Comment: The whole point of parentheses is you do the stuff inside parentheses first.

Comment: The question is why do you ask, or what else do you think it could be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a calculator for this. You can do it by hand:

If $h(x)=x^2$, then

$$\begin{align}
f(g(h(x)))&=f(g(x^2))\\
&=f(x^2-7)\\&
=(x^2-7)^2-2\\&
=x^4-14x^2+47.
\end{align}$$

Notice that

$$g(x^2)\neq(x-7)^2.$$

On the other hand,

$$g(x)^2=(x-7)^2.$$

This is because, with $g(x^2)$, we are squaring the independent variable $x$, not the whole function.

Comment: My question is why is it f(x^2 - 7) and not f(x^2-14x+49)? Thank you for the other breakdown!

Comment: @Eric, I made an edit to my answer. Let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you!